# Ionic Cordova FingerPrint Authentication

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I am new to Ionic. I need help with setting up Fingerprint and or passcode authentication in my application. I used Android Fingerprint Auth Cordova plugin. On running it on my android device,although, its working fine, But, It has a cancel button, which when user clicks, it opens the app. I want to disable this cancel button and block user from entering the application.

Below is the code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AndroidFingerprintAuth } from '@ionic-native/android-fingerprint-auth/ngx';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    public androidFingerprintAuth: AndroidFingerprintAuth
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.androidFingerprintAuth.isAvailable()
  .then((result)=> {
    if(result.isAvailable){
      // it is available

      this.androidFingerprintAuth.encrypt({ clientId: 'myAppName', username: 'myUsername', password: 'myPassword',maxAttempts:5,dialogTitle:'Confirm finger print to continue',userAuthRequired:true })
        .then(result => {
           if (result.withFingerprint) {
               console.log('Successfully encrypted credentials.');
               console.log('Encrypted credentials: ' + result.token);
           } else if (result.withBackup) {
             console.log('Successfully authenticated with backup password!');
           } else console.log('Didn\'t authenticate!');
        })
        .catch(error => {
           if (error === this.androidFingerprintAuth.ERRORS.FINGERPRINT_CANCELLED) {
             console.log('Fingerprint authentication cancelled');
           } else console.error(error)
        });

    } else {
      // fingerprint auth isn't available
    
    }
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
    });
  }
}
```

Please suggest how to disable cancel button.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there login page? Where use this code? In the first page after the first page?

Answer (score 0):

The current version of **Android Fingerprint Auth** [v1.5.0](https://github.com/mjwheatley/cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth/releases/tag/v1.5.0) has no configuration to disable that "Close" button or even redirect or close the app from that dialog component provided. Currently most of the plugins that displays some kind of UI when they are activated will redirect to the application when they close or are "destroyed". You can modify the "Use Backup" button using the "**disableBackup**" property set to **false** in the options object, it will remove that button.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but I found answer to this. To disable or hide cancel button, I did changes to FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment.java file in plugins folder to hide/disable cancel button as shown below:

Path:
ProjectPath>\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\cordova\plugin\android\fingerprintauth\FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment.java

Code changes:

```
 int cancel_button_id = getResources()
                .getIdentifier("cancel_button", "id", FingerprintAuth.packageName);
        mCancelButton = (Button) v.findViewById(cancel_button_id); 
// Added below lines of code for hiding/disabling cancel button
> mCancelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
>         mCancelButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Thanks